# In what order do tags appear on a question?

Tags: support, tags

When I tag a question (or edit the tags of an existing question), I can enter the tag names in a whitespace-separated list, in any random order. However, when I submit the form, they appear in a different order.

By what criteria are they sorted?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The list of tags is automatically ordered by popularity (i.e., the number of questions that each tag has been used on) at the time the question was last edited (the order is cached for a particular question and is only updated when the question is edited). The tag with the highest question count appears first.