# Please do not sort the tags by question count

Tags: feature-request, tags

I recently [created a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26273686/1521227) and assigned the tags I assumed characterize the question best in the order I thought most applicable, which in my case was

[angular-ui-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-grid) [sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sorting) [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

As stated in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253271/1521227) the tags are ordered based on the question count at the time the question was asked or edited, which results in the following order for my question:

[javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) [sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sorting) [angular-ui-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-grid)

That in turn prepends the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag to the question title in google's search results.

In this case the question title *"How to access the sorted rows in an angularjs ui-grid?"* already contains the necessary keywords "angularjs" and "ui-grid", so no harm done here.

But in general I would like to decide myself which tag is the most important to my question, and thus gets displayed in the search engine results. **So here's my feature request: Please do no longer re-order the tags, but rather leave them in the order the user has had them applied.**

Answer (score -4):

The tag order by question count has the advantage to go from the most general category to the most specific category. This makes orientation easier for the reader. Also the classification doesn't depend on the order of the tags. Basically all tags are equally important.

If you have 5 tags and you want to set the tag order yourself there would be 120 possible arrangements for basically the same thing.

It's not clear how much a certain order of tags influences the position in a search result of a search engine. Maybe they even learned that the last tag is the most specific and therefore probably the most important too.

An important tag tends to be used in the question body and should be. In your case: mention "angularjs" at least in the question text if you feel this is the most important tag. For example, right at the beginning of the questions seems like a good place: "In angularjs there is this feature..."

Maybe we should reverse the tag order if search engines really have problems with it, but we should not give the order completely free because there is almost no gain from it while this would additionally confuse people. I'm just so used to see the most general category first but I also read all the other tags.

Comment: _"Maybe we should reverse the tag order"_ What? Nope. Don't go changing things based on assumptions.

Comment: Also: _"An important tag tends to be used in the question title or body and should be."_ Nope. Tags shouldn't be used in the question's title for the sake of using tags in there. Unless the tag is required in the question, like _"php equivalent of c# function X"_

Comment: @Cerbrus I wish I could, but I cannot just go changing things here. This wasn't even a feature request but a mere possibility to cover all bases.