# Unchanged tags show up in diff

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, revision-history

What happened in [this revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2435525/revisions)? That edit seems to first have removed the tags [dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dom), [forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forms) and [attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attributes), and added the tags [forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forms) and [dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dom) again:

[image: dom and forms tag show up twice in the diff, once as being removed and once as being added]

How can this be? I thought there was [no order](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253271/1048572) in the tags, and removing+reappending should not should not show up as any change - there was no change?

Comment: [tag:html] has gained popularity relative to [tag:forms] and [tag:dom] since the post was last edited, so the tag *order* changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags get ordered by popularity (as per the answer you linked). Sometimes between edits, the popularity of the tags changes. So when you make a new edit, the tags get removed from their old position and added to their new position, thus updating their order.

Comment: Oh, I thought the order would get applied when tags were *shown*, not when they were created/edited.

Comment: Which may make this by-design, though a questionable and unintuitive one.