# How is the order of tags decided and why does it change when editing?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm working on retagging all of the [triangle] questions, and I noticed that when I edit the tags, their order changes. Often, [triangle] is last in the list before an edit, but after pressing the "edit tags" button, it changes position. I had thought maybe one order was the order the user chose, and the other was alphabetical, but that's definitely not the case as demonstrated here:

before editing:
[image: The tags before editing]

and while editing:
[image]

I don't know about the user's ordering, but neither is alphabetical.

Please note that this is not asking the same thing as [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253269/in-what-order-do-tags-appear-on-a-question) which is about the order of display. I'm asking about why the order changes when edited. It appears from the comments that perhaps not everyone sees the order the same. Maybe this a bug, or even a feature?

Comment: How did that not show up in my search? Also, I don't think it's quite the same as I'm asking why it changes rather than what order they're in.

Comment: how did you search? I just did this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btags%5D+order

Comment: I searched for http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=why+does+tag+order+change+when+editing. I got about 6 responses related to tags and order, but not to why they change when editing. Lesson learned! Also, when editing the questions, only about 5 related ones showed up, and they weren't really related.

Comment: I believe.... Tags are ordered by the user posting the question, so they appear in the order defined by the user initially when you view and edit the question. Upon editing tags, that is where the order will change to display the most popular tags first.

Comment: I guess my question would be, "why?" It's confusing to an editor. If I'm trying to remove or change a specific tag, I click "edit" and then as I'm about to remove the offending tag, it shifts to a different position potentially causing me to delete the wrong one.

Comment: @Tanner: that is incorrect. They are *always* ordered by popularity at edit time. What order the original author uses is not preserved.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for clarifying. So the original order makes no difference whatsoever?

Comment: Also, is [slimdx] really more popular than [c#]? According to the tags wiki, [slimdx] only has ~250 questions, whereas [c#] has > 720,000

Comment: @user1118321: back in [october 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1559511/revisions) it was more popular.

Comment: @Tanner: the order is set when the revision is saved to the database. Author order doesn't influence it.

Comment: @user1118321: the revisions show also that your *before* could not have been true. The order you show as *before* is the order **after** saving.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I assure you that the "before" picture is an unedited screenshot taking before editing. Another possibility that maybe you didn't think of is that the revision history uses the same sorting as whichever one it matches for you? Or maybe it varies by browser? (I'm on Safari 8.0.3 rev. 10600.3.18 on Yosemite 14C109.)

Comment: @user1118321: let me put it this way: I cannot reproduce what you saw with any browser. The revisions page for the question shows that the initial order from before editing matched your 'edit' screenshot. The other screenshot matches what we see *now*, after editing. As such, I am skeptical about your claim that the order of tags changed when you edited.

Comment: OK, so that's definitely odd, but it still leaves me with my original question. Why does it change? I believe the changing is causing errors for some people, so I'd like to draw attention to it.