# Does the order of tags matter when tagging a question?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/750198/revisions) where a couple of edits had been made, including some to the tags. In particular, the order of the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml) tags had been reversed:

[image]

Out of curiosity, does changing the order make any difference? Should a particular format be followed when tagging (most popular DESC/alphabetical/etc)?

If not, why was the order changed for this question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In what order do tags appear on a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253269/in-what-order-do-tags-appear-on-a-question) and [How is the order of tags decided and why does it change when editing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287446/how-is-the-order-of-tags-decided-and-why-does-it-change-when-editing)

Comment: The question pertains to why the order was changed during the edit in which case the first is not a duplicate and the second does not have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No, order doesn't matter. The tags are sorted, after every edit, by their current popularity (number of posts with the tag).

Because they are sorted *every time you edit* the order can change over time as tags grow in popularity at different rates.

It may be that tags were not sorted early on in the site's history, thus making it slightly more likely tags shift when edited today.

Comment: Ah, so when adding in a new tag, the old ones got auto-sorted. That sound right?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: exacly right.

Comment: Imo, this rule is not always very relevant. As an exemple, a lot of questions about  `angularjs` are also tagged `javascript`. As `javascript` is more popular than `angularjs`, it is shown first (in search engine it is displays as `javascript - Question title`) even when the question is **mostly** about AngularJS. Anyway, I don't know how it could be improved ;D

Comment: @MartijnPieters how does this affect syntax highlighting for questions tagged with multiple language tags?

Comment: @NickA then none are used and it's set to 'default'. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: Sadly it doesn't - because I just realized this while always having tagged my questions in order of importance.