# Should the ability to order tags manually be included for SEO purposes?

Tags: feature-request, tags, seo

I have a question I recently added a bounty on. I wanted to add a reactjs tag to it. However, reactjs is added as the first tag when I do this. According to [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355883/does-the-order-of-tags-matter-when-tagging-a-question), this is because [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) is a way more popular tag, with many more questions than the other tags.

The reason this matters in my opinion is because I noticed that the first tag is added to the beginning of the text within the `<title>` tag of the rendered HTML for the question (i.e the text that appears in the browser tab).

For SEO reasons and proper indexing, I would rather this question show "gatsby" or maybe "graphql" in the title.

I know the keywords in the title is only one factor when it comes to search engine indexing, and that keywords in general play a large role. However, in order to maximize visibility of a question to relevant askers, I think enabling the ordering of tags would be a good option.

Comment: Well, the obvious solution is to not use reactjs if it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: @Braiam Well.. The main tech being used is used by people who program in reactjs... Gatsby = React... I can see what you're saying for sure. But is it bad SO etiquette to include a tag that's probably going to expose your question to more users who may be familiar with your issue? Perhaps it is, and I'm simply out-of-line here fundamentally.

Comment: Another thought... Even without reactjs, I'd like to reorder so that gatsby shows rather than graphql in the title. Both tags are most definitely relevant.

Comment: "it bad SO etiquette to include a tag that's probably going to expose your question to more users who may be familiar with your issue?" it's not etiquette, is practically. You want an answer to your question. You make sure to target the users that are necessary to solve it. If reactjs is necessary, then use the tag. If it's not, then don't use it.

Comment: @Braiam Seems like you're over-simplifying the (albeit simple) situation. "If reactjs is necessary" sounds to me like a borderline subjective and potentially arguable question. If reactjs is part of the tech I'm using, and I want maximum exposure for my question, then I suppose you could say it's "necessary." However, looks kinda like I'm outnumbered here :) Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 8):

Why would you care about SEO for something like this?

Users looking for questions to answer are **not** using Google or another generalized search engine to find these questions. For those SEO is irrelevant (even more so in a bountied question).

The users that will get to your question through a search engine will be looking for **answers**, and for those the "natural" order of the tags (more popular first) makes more sense, since the most popular tag of the tags used on a question is the one most likely to be the most relevant in regards of the issues dealt with on the question.

Comment: I'm more thinking about people in the future looking for an answer to the the same question that happen to look up the problem they are having on google, or other search engines.

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted you, as I appreciate your input. However, could you explain why you think the natural order of the tags make more sense?

Comment: That's fine, someone disagreed with my answer. Weird that they didn't agree with your FR at the same time, but maybe it's simply that they found my answer poor or unclear.

Comment: I see your update. I would counter that sometimes question askers include a more popular tag simply for more visibility on stack overflow itself, even though it's not the most relevant tag for the question.

Comment: If the argument is "some users mistag their posts, so we better let them reorder the tags", I don't think it's a very strong argument.

Comment: Also I wanted to mention that pertaining to my question the way I intended it to be received, the first half of your answer is irrelevant. I was only referring to people having the same problem, and hence asking the same question. Not people looking to answer the question... I think it's rare that google would be used for question answerers... I never even considered that tbh.

Comment: Is it really a mistag though? A more popular tag can still be a secondary tech used regarding a particular question.