# Issue with tags on questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, design, title

Could tags be moved (or duplicated) up above the content of the question near the title or something? When the posted question is rather long, the tags are hidden way down below it.

Just had a couple of downvotes because someone posted a question, where the title and content didn't specify the language anywhere. It looked like c/c#, but ended up being javascript which you would have never known except for the tag way down below it. Immediately had responses of "where is the .net tag on this". If users would add one extra word to their questions mentioning what tech they were using it would have also helped.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have any questions. Did you delete it after the downvotes? There could be more at issue with your question than just the code looking like a different language and the tagging, but we would have to see the question to have the context to know what's up.

Comment: Worth note, on the question list, tags are shown below the title. Other users would have likely seen the tags before going to the question. Are you sure the downvotes were due to what you've stated? Did a user comment to this effect?

Comment: Here is the original post, nothing in the heading or the content specifies language. I made the mistake of assuming it was c# when it was in fact a JS question, and quickly received two down votes because I missed the tag. Yes I deleted it. Just realized that cleared up the negative rep, thanks.     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828098/how-would-you-shorten-this-switch-case-statement/

Comment: Okay, so you're saying you _answered_ the question and answered in the wrong language? You should edit your question here to clarify that a bit. It reads like you asked a question and received downvotes for others assuming it was a different language.

Comment: Correct, there was no mention of the lang they were using in title/content when they asked their question. Will edit, thanks.

Comment: There are not supposed to be Tags in the titles as it is just redundant clutter given the tag set each question is given.

Comment: One way to avoid confusion is to filter questions using tags. That way, every question you see is related to one or the other of the tags you filtered to.

Comment: Interestingly in the mobile version of the SO website the tags are exactly below the title and above the content. So it should clearly be a matter of consistency to handle it in the desktop version the same or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for something like that.

One should always read the entire question well and also check the tags before posting an answer. If you don't read it well and post a wrong answer, that's your fault for being impatient. There is no need for the tag to be in the question. And, when you take look at the question from the questions page, you are bound to see which language it is tagged.

Most users visit questions based on their tags. They would only check questions from specific tags and would view question based on tags like [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) or [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)  or [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) or whichever tag they prefer. So, they would know which tag it belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

It is not required to explicitly mention what language you are using in the body of a question, and unless it flows naturally, the information really should not be in the title. That is the purpose of tags.

Of course, that's not what you're asking for. You're asking to move the tags so you know what the question is asking before you answer. There's already two places to see this, however: The question list, and the bottom of the question.

This is what you see in the question lists:

<kbd>[image: Question List, Tags circled]</kbd>

As you can see, before you even click into the question, you're presented with the tags. You should check these *before* going into the question to see if it's a question that's pertinent to your programming knowledge if you're looking to answer questions.

At the bottom of a question, you also see the tags. You have to see this part of the question at some point if you wish to comment, read the comments, or answer, *unless* you simply hit <kbd>End</kbd> and scroll up to answer. However, if you intend to answer, you should double check all of the details of the question, *especially* the tags.

Also note that, as mentioned by [Plutonix](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1070452/plutonix) [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291247/issue-with-tags-on-questions#comment181427_291255), the primary* tag for a question is displayed in the page title/browser tab. You can always just glance up to see one of the tags on the question, quite likely the language tag.

**tl;dr:** This isn't really needed, as we already have at least one prominent spot where you should look at the tags before you even go into the question: The question list.

---

<sub>* - Primary tag being the tag first in the list. See [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253269/in-what-order-do-tags-appear-on-a-question?lq=1) for how tags are ordered in a question.</sub>

Comment: Ok I will let it go, note that in all 4 of the examples above every one mentions the tech being used somewhere in their heading or content.  Agreed I mistakingly missed the tag, just thought it might be helpful on long questions. I will pull this post down.

Comment: @Christopher Those just happened to be the first four on the list when I took the screenshot. There's certainly no requirement to include that information in the question, mainly because of the tags. My point was more that the tags are already prominently displayed, and should be checked before you go into a question you intend to answer. As you answer more questions, you'll start picking this up quicker and likely automatically check the tags for any information not in the question itself, such as libraries. It's all good. :)

Comment: The "primary" tag also shows in the browser/tab title bar

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks, I had forgotten about that.