# Consider explicit tag order when generating titles

Tags: feature-request, tags, title

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253271/27358), the tags on a question are ordered based on the tag popularity. This means the most popular tag on a question will be prepended to the title, even if it's not actually the most relevant tag to the question. It would be nice if we kept track of the actual input order of tags and used the first in that list for the title, instead of the most popular.

(Example: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399249/building-a-lazy-sequence-out-of-io-data), which was originally tagged [ruby] even though it's primarily a Clojure question, because the OP gave a Ruby example of what s/he was trying to do in Clojure. This means, among other things, that it's the #3 question in a Google search for *ruby sequence IO*, and looks from the title as though its answer should be relevant to that search, when it isn't. It doesn't show up in the first page of results for *clojure sequence IO*.)

Comment: What's even more annoying is that there's no preview of what tag might be appended to the title.

Comment: Yeah, I think it ought to go in the on-page article title, too.

Comment: Honestly to me this is just a sign that the tag shouldn't be there in the first place.  You put tags on a question because you want experts in that topic to come to your question, and ruby experts shouldn't be directed to this question.  That there is some ruby in the question doesn't mean it should use that tag.

Comment: That's arguably true for this question (and in fact I deleted the tag), but I don't think it's necessarily true for all questions that exhibit this problem.