# Re-ordering tags for search engine results

Tags: discussion

According to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253269/in-what-order-do-tags-appear-on-a-question), tags are sorted by the number of questions at the time of asking/last edited. A higher number of questions indicates a tag's priority in the order.

In a Google search of "updating https password git" the number three result is [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195304/how-to-update-password-for-git)

While this question is tagged with `git`, it's also tagged with `osx`. In search results, it appears this way (Image upload is failing):

**osx - How to update password for git? - Stack Overflow**

With `osx` preceding the question.

As it turns out, there is an OSX specific answer to this question (With regards to the arguments passed to a command; the command is the same across different OS's), but it seems odd to me that a `git` question would be prefaced with `osx` in search results. It's a minor thing, but shouldn't users be allowed to order tags themselves?

Comment: That was a single example. I don't "want" anything out of that particular question.

Comment: I'm not an SE dev but: as the tags are stored denormalized in the posts table it would require an system initiated tag edit or some other batch-script to get the tag order updated. As load time performance is a design feature any processing that doesn't help getting content quicker to the user is probably sacrificed. There isn't a specific path for search engine crawlers so you can't just update the tag order when Google comes by and detecting a crawler basic on its user agent is again not helping in serving content quicker.

Comment: I don't see much benefit for tag ordering by users as well. Only to have roll-back wars over them ...

Comment: @yellowantphil Maybe just "git - How to update password?" since tags shouldn't be in the question titles anyways.

Comment: @yellowantphil touche